# How to add Data To GridView From TextBox & DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have controls like TextBox, DropDownList and button on page.

When I enter data to TextBox, DropDown and if I click on button then it should add to GridView cell's TextBox and DropDownList respectively.

Example, When I enter the data to text box and hit the save button, I need to show it to GridView.

No data from DB.

May i know how to do it? Any Example code for reference ?  Kindly advise, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put another button to insert data into database and write below code on click event.

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string str1 = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
        string str2 = oItem.Cells[1].Text;
        string str3 = oItem.Cells[2].Text;
        insertData(str1, str2, str3);
    }
}
public void insertData(string str1,string str2,string str3)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection strig");
    string sql = "insert into tbl1 (column1,column2,column3) values ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: HI HItesh, When i put Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?stat=insert"); , the data only record the first key in, for the rest data is gone. any ideas ? thank you

Comment: User Hitesh provided [this link](http://hemantsaliya.blogspot.in/2013/03/add-textbox-value-to-gridview-without.html) in his other answer which was deleted.